# Authorization failure when using JS fetch from google docs add in

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch-api, urlfetch

I am working on an add-on for Google Docs (slides and sheets), and I am running into an issue when trying to get information from an external endpoint in a custom dialog window. After opening the dialog, when the user enters in specific data a rest api is called to pull back some data (an SVG element).

However, The problem is that when the request is made I am getting a 401 response (Unauthorized)

```
var data = {"name":"value"};
var apiKey = "key";
var payload = {
   'code': code,
   'apiKey': apiKey,
   'theme':'light'
};
const response = await fetch('url:4443', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload) 
    });
```

When I make the same call using curl (outside of google) everything returns correctly

```
curl -d '{"code":"graph LR\nA[Hard edge] -->|Link text| B(Round edge)\nB --> C{Decision}\nC -->|One| D[Result one]\nC -->|Two| E[Result two]","apiKey":"[KEY]","theme":"light"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://[URL]:4443/
```

Most of the results I get when searching for an answer are referring to making calls INTO a google apps script, and not out of it.

(I dont want to use URLFetch api to make calls from the server side, since it would block the UI and doesnt seem like the right place to do it anyways - since I am getting data to display on the dialog already open)

Are there any security restriction when making external calls from a google add on?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your issue, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. Unfortunately, I cannot know the specification of the API you want to use. So, I'm not sure `'url:4443'` can be requested by the fetch API of Javascript. If my proposed modification was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I mean, ":4443" is just the port number to the resource uri - I deleted the actual endpoint and used "url" here

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I actually had it setup to use "body" originally, but found something on SO where someone had a slightly different issue, but their fix was to change it from "body" to "payload" - it didnt help here. :) `, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I apologize for my poor skill. I would like to study more.